# How to use ENQUEUE_RENDER_COMMAND in 4.27?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, texture2d

I would like to convert old code (from 4.26 to 4.27) but this code contains something removed in 4.27 of Unreal Engine.

```cpp
/* OLD CODE */
ENQUEUE_UNIQUE_RENDER_COMMAND_TWOPARAMETER(
            UpdateTextureRegionsData,
            FUpdateTextureRegionsData*, RegionData, RegionData,
            bool, bFreeData, bFreeData,
            {
            for (uint32 RegionIndex = 0; RegionIndex < RegionData->NumRegions; ++RegionIndex)
            {
                int32 CurrentFirstMip = RegionData->Texture2DResource->GetCurrentFirstMip();
                if (RegionData->MipIndex >= CurrentFirstMip)
                {
                    RHIUpdateTexture2D(
                        RegionData->Texture2DResource->GetTexture2DRHI(),
                        RegionData->MipIndex - CurrentFirstMip,
                        RegionData->Regions[RegionIndex],
                        RegionData->SrcPitch,
                        RegionData->SrcData
                        + RegionData->Regions[RegionIndex].SrcY * RegionData->SrcPitch
                        + RegionData->Regions[RegionIndex].SrcX * RegionData->SrcBpp
                        );
                }
            }
            if (bFreeData)
            {
                FMemory::Free(RegionData->Regions);
                FMemory::Free(RegionData->SrcData);
            }
            delete RegionData;
        });
```

I'm trying to convert this part of code especially. This is what I have now.

```cpp
/* NEW CODE */
ENQUEUE_RENDER_COMMAND(UpdateTextureRegionsData)(
            [RegionData, bFreeData, Texture](FRHICommandListImmediate& RHICmdList)
            {
                for (uint32 RegionIndex = 0; RegionIndex < RegionData->NumRegions; ++RegionIndex)
                {
                    int32 CurrentFirstMip = Texture->FirstResourceMemMip;
                    if (RegionData->MipIndex >= CurrentFirstMip)
                    {
                        RHIUpdateTexture2D(
                            RegionData->Texture2DResource->GetTexture2DRHI(), //THIS LINE PROVIDES ME AN ERROR
                            RegionData->MipIndex - CurrentFirstMip,
                            RegionData->Regions[RegionIndex],
                            RegionData->SrcPitch,
                            RegionData->SrcData
                            + RegionData->Regions[RegionIndex].SrcY * RegionData->SrcPitch
                            + RegionData->Regions[RegionIndex].SrcX * RegionData->SrcBpp
                        );
                    }
                }
                if (bFreeData) {
                    FMemory::Free(RegionData->Regions);
                    FMemory::Free(RegionData->SrcData);
                }
                delete RegionData;
            });
```

The fact is the method GetTexture2DRHI seems not existing anymore under Texture2DResource so I can't convert properly the old code to new one.

How could I get the Texture2DRHI from Texture2DResource ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved this by now, but this is for future reference. I was doing opencv integration tutorial ([integration tutorial](https://nerivec.github.io/old-ue4-wiki/pages/integrating-opencv-into-unreal-engine-4.html)) by Ginku and basically met with identical code. I changed code as you did except instead `RegionData->Texture2DResource->GetTexture2DRHI()` I used `Texture->Resource->GetTexture2DRHI()`.

See the full code from the link.